# the_author_meta('user_url', $author->ID) not working properly. how can I solve this?

Tags: users, user-roles, author, multi-author

I have 2 authors and an admin on my blog.
I am using the following code in my contributors.php

```
function contributors() {
        global $wpdb;

        $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");

        foreach($authors as $author) {

        echo the_author_image($author->ID);

        echo the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID) . '</br>' ;
        echo the_author_meta('user_url', $author->ID) . '</br>';
        echo the_author_meta('description', $author->ID) . '</br>' ;
        echo the_author_meta('user_email', $author->ID) . '</br></br>' ;

        }
        }

        contributors();
```

It's printing all authors' and admin's photo, name, description and email perfectly.

but it not printing the user link correctly.

- for admin or user ID 1 it's printing the blog URL
- for 1st author or user ID 2, it's printing the correct URL.
- for 2nd author or user ID 3, it's printing nothing.

what is the problem? how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the database for User's url. Maybe that's what they used for registering.

What about this scenario -

- For admin, the default value of url is the blog url.
- User ID 2 used a url when registering.
- User ID 3 kept the url field blank when registering.

You should fist check their url from the database. It resides in `wp_users` table(I am assuming that you have used the table prefix `wp_`).

**EDIT:**

`the_author_posts_link()` and `the_author_meta('user_url',$userID)` have different functionality.

`the_author_posts_link()` display displays a link to all posts by an author.

`the_author_meta('user_url',$userID)` displays their homepage url.

So, these are two different things. I think your best bet is to use the following to get what you are trying to achevie instead of `the_author_meta('user_url', $userID)`. You can't also use `the_author_posts_link` as it takes no argument and have to be used inside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $author->ID ); ?>"><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author->ID ); ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. but I think no need to check database. because when I use `echo the_author_posts_link();` on my **single.php** the post shows the proper author and it redirects to his page when it's clicked. my users links are like this - www.mysite.com/author/mysiteadmin - www.mysite.com/author/user1 - www.mysite.com/author/user2

Comment: sorry for that. you are right. my question is wrong. `echo the_author_meta('user_url', $author->ID) . '</br>';` is printing the website URL they gave. I did not notice that. but actually i want to print the author link. `get_echo the_author_link($author->ID).'<br/>';` is not working. so how can I do that.

Comment: @RiffazStarr I have updated my answer. See if `get_author_posts_url` works for you.

Comment: yeah.. that's it..  working like charm.. thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Glad I could help.